# Replacing Pandas Dataframe Header with Date column but in ascending order

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have a Dataframe of 5k+ rows that looks like this. It has Date column which has Month/Year format. The Date column is in string format.

```
Name   Date     Friends
A    June 2017   100
A    April 2017  45
A    March 2016  180
B    June 2017   43
B    April 2017  23
B    March 2016  23
C    June 2017   64
C    April 2017  643
C    March 2016  344
```

I want to format in the following way, which makes unique values from Date Column into headers. But in the ascending order according to Month/Year.

```
Name    March 2016  April 2017  June 2017
A         180         45            100
B          23         23            43
C         344         643           64
```

I tried using the Pandas function - Pivot.

```
df=df.pivot(index='Name',columns='Date',values='Friends')
```

But this doesn't sort the month/year in ascending order but instead it does in alphabetically order. Also Pivot transforms the dataframe in Stacked format.

Any ideas on how to achieve the desired format?

Comment: You can sort them first and group it. Make sure the date column is datetime format

Answer (score 0):

Something like this,

```
df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df=df.sort_values(['Date'], ascending=False)
df.groupby(['Name', 'Date'], sort=False)['Friends'].sum().unstack('Date')
```

Comment: It worked. Now I just have to figure out to change date time format header to it's earlier %M %Year format.

Comment: That almost solves my problem, I have coordinates and not dates, how can I do that coordinates (let's say X) will be within range? For example X=1,2,3,4,5 will be thr same and X=6,7,8,9 and so on and so forth?